# Add new EditText component to an Activity at run time

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can i add a new EditText component to an Activity layout? I don't want to add the component from the GUI editor statically, but add it to the activity at run time, for example when the user clicks a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the EditText in the layout XML for your activity with android:visibility="gone".
When you want to show the EditText do:

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);
ed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ur_layout);
EditText editTextView = new EditText(this);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
editTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
linearLayout.addView(editTextView);
```